# Errors while installing modules with Pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

While installing modules with pip, I am always getting the following error:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\agniva roy\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install os': The system cannot find the file specified.`

To be Note: I had recently updated from Python 3.8 to Python 3.9.

Comment: is pip installed in the new python39? i.e., does `C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe` exist?

Comment: Thank man! You really helped me! pip was not installed while in the installation process of Python 3.9 it is working well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall and install again with the command below. Can you try it ?

```
python -m pip install -U --force pip
```

after it, I think you can install any module.

Comment: This command give me the following error: "C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named pip What shall I do know?

Comment: https://michlstechblog.info/blog/python-install-python-with-pip-on-windows-by-the-embeddable-zip-file/  then u should install pip. hope this will fix.

Comment: Yes I have done it and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

actually I recommend to you uninstall this version of python and install it again with activating set Python path in your operating system automatically.